# alignment of newsletter page is not correct in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id ="header">
    <a href="index" class = "logo">
      <img src = "logo.png" alt = "" /> 
    </a>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>Share</li> |
        <li>Join</li> |
        <li>See Safty Tips</li> |
        <li>Settings</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <img src="accident.png" alt="">
    <div id="right-content">
      <h2>Hit and Run No Injuries</h2>
      <p>2.610 miles from your new neighbor<br />
        May 20, 2015 at 12.34 PM </p>
      <h4>California HWP 2 - High Level</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="secure_v5">
      <li id="li-incident">
        <a class="inviteLink dark" href="/v5/Resources.aspx?IFrameURL=Invitationv5&amp;vn=&amp;gORn=1">See Incident Location</a>
      </li>                
      <li id="login-signup">
        <a class="button dark"  href="V4/Login.aspx?v5=1">Share Incident with Friends</a>
      </li>                
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="thanks">

    <p>Sincerely,<br />
      The AlertID Team</p>
  </div>
  <p style="text-align:center;">This sponsor is helping to protect your neighborhood</p>

  <div class="footer-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/AlertID" class="sf" target="_blank"></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/AlertID" class="st" target="_blank"></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/AlertIDvideo" class="sy" target="_blank"></a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

and here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryadw7jn/) , (didn't include images)

When i run this code, some alignment is not correct,

I need something same like [**this**](http://s9.postimg.org/8vjysluxb/Alert_ID_newsletter_v4.jpg)

I just confused with which exact `css` can be used, Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are going to create an EDM: 1.Use Table 2. Use inline css

Comment: @RLam: can you please provide jsfiddle.. if it means,, it will help me easily,, thanks

Comment: can anyone help please?

Comment: hi all.. here is my updated link http://jsfiddle.net/b50g7nva/

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML tables to control the design layout and some presentation. You may be used to using pure CSS layouts for your web pages, but that approach just won’t hold up in an email environment.

Use inline CSS to control other presentation elements within your email, such as background colors and fonts.

Comment: Adding onto this, all your CSS should be inline, not included in a CSS file. Some email software do not allow outside files to be accessed. Also the HTML5 elements need to be removed and replaced by `divs`. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/ is a great tool to learn how to write Email templates

Comment: this is what we're talking about - you have to redo it using tables.  http://jsfiddle.net/bvs7wrqc/

Comment: @RobScott: here is my jsfiddle after some modification http://jsfiddle.net/b50g7nva/

Answer (score 0):

You just put **div #right-content** to right
try it on CSS.

```
#right-content {
float:right;
width:600px;
}

#right-content h2{
text-align:center;
}
```

I create a little attribute to h2 inside **div #right-content**
and define a fixed width for right-content. It's necessary because of attribute **float: right**.

Comment: try to reset margin, padding and border on css
        `body {margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;}`